# How to open local file with react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

Unable to open local file using **react-native-webview**

I'm currently trying to open a local file in react-native-webview within my React Native app. The file is located in the app's internal directory, specifically in FileSystem.documentDirectory. I've tried using the WebView component with the source prop set to the file's URI, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const App = () => {
  const fileName = 'file.pdf';
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${fileName}`;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{ uri: fileUri }} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However, when I run the app, I get an error or the WebView shows a blank screen. I've made sure that the file file.pdf exists in the correct location.

Is there something I'm missing or is there a different approach I should take to open a local file using react-native-webview? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2397), issue on GitHub:

> PDF viewing is not a feature of the Android Webview or even of the
> Chrome browser on Android.

But, if your PDF file was hosted online, you could use Google Drive as just a proxy to render your PDF file, as follows:

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const yourPdfURL="https://example/document.pdf"

render(
    <WebView
        source={{ `uri: https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${yourPdfURL}`}}
        style={{ width:"100%", height:"100%"}}
    />
)
```

If you really need to render a local PDF file, use the [react-native-pdf](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf) module instead, like the following code:

```js
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

[...]

render (
    <Pdf
        source={uri:"file:///absolute/path/to/xxx.pdf"}
    />
)
```

Don't forget to upvote and mark as solution if this answer helped you in solving your problem.